# How to get only user created properties using microsoft.cci Members?

Tags: c#, t4, fxcop

I'm learning T4, and am successfully interrogating my custom class for its member.

What I need however, is to bring out *only* the properties that I created, like FirstName, Surname, and Postcode.

Here's an example of what I'm actually getting when I use :

```
foreach(Microsoft.Cci.Member member in class.Members)
{
    if( member.IsPublic )
    {
        Write( member.Name + ",\n");
    }
}
```

get_FirstName,

set_FirstName,

get_Surname,

set_Surname,

FirstName,

Surname,

.ctor

Could anyone advise if its possible to just access the actual properties and their types?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to extract the properties from Members.  You can identify PropertyNode members by their NodeType, which will be NodeType.Property.  e.g.:

```
foreach (PropertyNode property in type.Members
                .Where(m => m.NodeType == NodeType.Property)
                .Cast<PropertyNode>())
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: You can also use type.Members.OfType<PropertyNode>()